# How to subtract two different values from two different columns and print if less than a value?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have the following kind of file separated by tabulations:

```
75  85
75  84
94  301
89  123
75  75
94  130
94  250
89  210
```

I need to print the lines where column 2 - column 1 > 80, so, it would look something like:

```
94  301
94  250
89  210
```

I've tried to use operators with `awk`, but I don't know how to do math using awk to print these lines, is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '$2 - $1 > 80' file
```

---

awk's default action is to print so this is saying if the condition (that column 2 minus column 1 is greater than 80) is met, print that line.

Comment: Awesome, it worked! I'll have that in mind when doing this kind of operations, thanks!